# Two authentication cookies in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Let's suppose we have a web-site where there are:

- Admin section
- Client section
- Guest(visitor) section

Obviously, the last one (Guest section) can be accessed by everyone while admin part - only by administrations and client part - only by registered clients.
Admins and clients have different model classes (Admin and User correspondingly), are stored in the different databases and we would like to use different authentication cookies for each of them. 
Is it possible to do with ASP.NET Core Identity?

We tried to use CookieName property during AddIdentity initialization but it appears that ApplicationCookie accessible there - is the same object, so the second definition simply rewrites the first one:

```
services
    .AddIdentity<User, UserRole>(opts => {
        opts.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieName = "Client";
        opts.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
          .    .    .    .    .   .   

    });



services
    .AddIdentity<Admin, AdminRole>(opts => {
        //the following lines rewrite cookie options from client's to admin's
        opts.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieName = "Admin";
        opts.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/admin/login");
          .    .    .    .    .   .   
    });
```

Comment: You are not supposed to have one Identity for each role, you are supposed to have one role for each security need. You most likely need a custom IdentityStore where you can decide whether to query User or Admin db according to some logic

Comment: Well, you may have them stored in different databases, but from the perspective of the application, they are all USERS. I know this doesn't answer your question but what I am trying to say is that maybe you should reconsider your design.

Comment: Sounds like 2 (or 3) different applications to me.

Answer (score 2):

Possible? Yes. You would need to create your own identity middleware to handle different cookies but it can be done.

Recommended? **NO**

There are 2 separate issues with security: authentication and authorization. Cookies work well for authentication (*who someone is*) and but you should use roles and claims for authorization (*what someone can do and has access to*), which is what you're trying to solve here.

ASP.NET's Identity framework already has great support for both Roles and Claims so you can use a standard user model for everyone, add an "admin" role for some users, and then add even more specific claims as needed.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction) for handling authorization is very detailed and gives you a great walkthrough of options. Both Roles and Claims can easily be enforced by adding them to a user profile and then using [Attributes] on your controller route methods, as shown below:

Roles:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class AdministrationAreaController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
    }
}
```

Claims:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "EmployeeOnly")]
public class ClientAreaController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: We are aware of the differences between authentication and authorization and the Roles/Claims approach for authorization.
Both those entities (User and Admin) have their own lists of roles for proper authorization behavior.

Comment: The reasons why we need to divide users and admins are:
1. We store them in two totally diffent places (users - in SQL DB, admins - in Azure table storage)
2.They have totally different set of properties (except maybe the name and password hash).
3. It's more secure. If a hacker figures out how to add an additional role/claim to some user - nothing terrible will happen. If they had been shared the same storage - adding an "Admin" role to some account would have allowed such hacker to get full access to the system.

Comment: "Users" in this case are authenticated parties to your application, that's all.  Cookies and identity are completely different from user data storage. It doesn't matter if there are different databases, you can use custom logic to check the proper db and still log them in with the same cookie space. You can also use a generic `User` model that contains all the properties possible or a Dictionary<> and then use a combination of roles (admin or client) and claims (specific permissions) to authenticate.

Comment: There is no security benefit here. ASP.NET Identity is already well designed with proper encryption of cookie credentials so there's no hacking possible. Even if that did happen, anyone can easily change the name of the cookie anyway so it makes no difference.

Comment: The security issue has nothing to do with the cookies. It's more about getting access to DB. For example "users" DB  can be stored on some remote server with less security and the "admins" DB is stored on the local server. If someone gets access to the "users" DB they still will not be able to control the whole system.
Anyway, the question is not about system architecture. It's about the concrete problem with the cookies.

Comment: The question has been answered, you can only do it with custom middleware and not the default Identity packages - however since you just repeated that it has nothing to do with cookies, there's no reason to use multiple cookie names. It's much better to just use some custom logic to handle checking both databases. Your application can then assign the "client" or "admin" during the login depending on the database, rather than storing that role in the database. That way even if someone has access to the users database, they still won't get an admin role.

Comment: Is there some documentation I can get regarding the creation of the custom middleware? Im trying to solve a similar issue where I need to have two users authenticated at the same time.

Comment: @LuisBecerril What are you asking specifically? The framework already supports multiple users logged in at the same time so that's likely not your actual problem. You can read about middleware on the .NET Core documentation site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware but it might be easier to just use cookie authentication for your site and check whatever backends or databases you need to during the signin process.

Comment: @ManiGandham This is my specific question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197530/multiple-users-same-browser-asp-identity