# Multiple users same browser asp identity

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-identity, owin

We have an application which has two user types. One of them is an administrator and the other one is a client. We are using AspNet identity to authenticate the user and issue a cookie. 
However, there is a scenario where the administrator and the user share the same browser. When the client logs in, the cookie gets overridden and when coming back to the administrator pages we lose authentication. The same happens the other way around (client is logged in first, then admin). 
Is there a way to support multiple authenticated users at the same time on the same browser?
Greetings.
Luis.

Comment: `support multiple authenticated users at the same time on the same browser` Are you trying to implement impersonation?

Comment: not really, I just want two simultaneus users on the same app

Comment: Nope, not possible. Not in Identity, not in any other web-application. You either admin or user. Need to log-out before becoming the other user. If you have both at the same time how does the application know which user is using the system?

Answer (score 0):

No, the browser has no understanding of any users. You set cookies and the browser sends back those cookies. The application then receives and checks those cookies to figure out the current user on the next request;

There's no way for the browser to know what cookies it should send back and there's no way for your server to know what the right user is other than reading those cookies. Why do you want 2 different user types sharing the same exact browser window anyway? That defeats the entire security model.

*If 2 people must share the same device*, then most browsers today support private windows or separate 'profiles' so you can have completely separate preferences and sessions without sharing any data. Here's a link to Chrome's profiles feature: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824

Comment: I have managed to create a separate cookie for every user in the application. I dont really want my browser to decide which cookie to send, but rather let the application decide which cookie to convert into the authenticated user. Can we somehow intercept the process of the cookie - identity conversion on asp identity?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. You shouldn't be creating separate cookies for each user, there should be a single cookie name used and the value (which is encrypted) contains the user's id and any other cached info like roles and claims. `ASP.NET Identity` does everything automatically, or you can use `Cookie Authentication` as a lower-level API which only manages cookies and you have to add in the password validation, roles, and claims structure yourself. How would the application know whether it's the "user" or the "admin" that's looking at the page?

Comment: In my application routes can only be consumed by one type of user. Therefore, my idea is that in case both cookies are present on the request, identify the route which was called and based on that decide which user will be used.