# How can I use multiple IdentityDbContext<T> in a project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I created two IdentityDbContext, one is AdminIdentityDbContext:IdentityDbContext, and another is StudentIdentityDbContext:IdentityDbContext.

And I created two controllers, one is:

```
    public class AdminAccountController : Controller
    {
        private UserManager<Admin> _userManager;
        private SignInManager<Admin> _signInManager;

        public AdminAccountController(UserManager<Admin> userManager, SignInManager<Admin> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }
Another is:

public class StudentAccountController : Controller
   {
       private UserManager<Student> _userManager;
       private SignInManager<Student> _signInManager;

       public StudentAccountController(UserManager<Student> studentManager, SignInManager<Student> signInManager)
       {
           _userManager = studentManager;
           _signInManager = signInManager;
       }
```

My Startup.cs is as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LibraryDemo.Data;
using LibraryDemo.Infrastructure;
using LibraryDemo.Models.DomainModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace LibraryDemo
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            services.AddDbContext<LendingInfoDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LendingInfoDbContext"));
            });
            services.AddDbContext<AdminIdentityDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AdminIdentityDbContext"));
            });
            services.AddDbContext<StudentIdentityDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("StudentIdentityDbContext"));
            });
            services.AddIdentity<Student, IdentityRole>(opts =>
                {
                    opts.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                    opts.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM0123456789";
                    opts.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                    opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                    opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<StudentIdentityDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opts =>
            {
                opts.LoginPath = "/StudentAccount/Login";
            });
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            DatabaseInitiator.Initial(app.ApplicationServices).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I got the site "/AdminAccount/Login", I got an error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[LibraryDemo.Models.DomainModels.Admin]' while attempting to activate 'LibraryDemo.Controllers.AdminAccountController'.
```

I don't like the Role feature, so what else can I do to resolve this problem? Thanks a lot.

I tried to change the schema of the DbContext but failed the same.

Additional context
I have put the project to github:
https://github.com/NanaseRuri/LibraryDemo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two authentication cookies in ASP.NET Core Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245965/two-authentication-cookies-in-asp-net-core-identity)

Comment: Consider a complete seperate context for identity and one or more seperate business contexts. For some background information check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079466/is-claims-based-authorization-appropriate-for-individual-resources/52100609#52100609

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not caused by your two DB contexts, it's because of the way you're setting up the Identity middleware.

You're setting up your Identity middleware with the `Student` and `IdentityRole` classes. This means that the `UserManager` is set up with the `Student` class, and therefore there's no instance of a `UserManager<Admin>` with the `Admin` class.

Based on your structure, it seems that what you need are two roles: one for students, and the other for admins. That way, you can keep a single user manager.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But if I want to save the data of Admin in another database, how to set up another authentication in the same project?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to setup `Identity` twice, with different databases. I found this question that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49073374/2698119

Comment: Thanks. But the question might not suit my situation, or could you tell me how can I use two authorizations including identity in a project ?